# How to count words which begin with 'a' or 'A' in log file (Using Ubuntu)

Tags: shell, ubuntu

Using this command:

```
egrep '^A.*$' || '^a.*$' sortlist | wc -l
```

If I use   `egrep '^A.*$' sortlist | wc -l` this is working .

Comment: What does this have to do with "linux-kernel"?

Comment: what is the content in sortlist file?

Comment: I took an example .Its just a text file .Which i will be implementing to find the count for the words starting with a or A .

Comment: what you have tried is finding the lines which starts with A or a, not words. your code will work if each line has single word and no spaces appended in start of line.